# Mock URI.parse for paperclip in Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, paperclip, rspec-rails

I'm currenyly working with a service that uses `URI.parse` and saves that image with paperclip.

This is what i have so far.

```
uri = URI.parse("http://example.com/my_image.jpg")

Image.new do |image|
  image.attachment = uri
  image.attachment_file_name = "image.jpg"
  image.attachment_content_type = "image/jpg"
end
```

this works perfectly and i'm not facing any errors with it.

I'm trying to do some tests in rspec, but i don't know how to mock that `URI.parse` and make it works.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you need to mock `URI.parse`? Why not just provide a valid URI?

Answer (score 0):

https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/2-99/docs/method-stubs

In your spec try

```
allow(URI).to receive(:parse).with(anything()).and_return bla
```

Where bla is what you want the method to return

Comment: Yes, that is something i'm doing. The problem is i don't know which thing  i should return.

Comment: Does the method work on the server? If so stick a raise or binding.pry just after you assign uri, see what it equals, and then use that for your value

Comment: Yes! it works in the server. Doing a binding pry i'm getting `URI::HTTPS` when doing `uri.class` but how to mock that and make it able to be saved in paperclip? or there is a way to do not run paperclip in rspec?

Comment: When you're in binding.pry, after you've assigned the variable 'uri', what does uri return? That's the value you want to stub

Comment: I've solved it out moving the URI.parse to a new method and mocking that method directly `allow(MyService).to receive(:my_method) { File.new }`

Comment: No worries!! :)

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it out moving the URI.parse to a new method and mocking that method directly `allow(MyService).to receive(:my_method) { File.new }`